# When ViewModel is changed to a different instance a bound RadioButton is reset to False

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radio-button

I reproduced this issue in a pretty simple .NET 4.0 test project.

Using MVVM, I have a view with a user control on it. When the user clicks a button, I need to replace the user control's data context so it points to another instance of the same class. When that happens, the value of a bound radio button in the user control is reset, i.e. the ConvertBack method of my converter BooleanToRadioButtonConverter is called with a value of false.

My questions are: **why does this happen and how do I work around it?**

I want to preserve the state of the ViewModels and be able to switch back and forth.

Here is my test project's code:

The parent view:

```
   <StackPanel>
      <converters:RadioButtons DataContext="{Binding RadioButtonVM, Mode=OneWay}" />
      <TextBlock Margin="20 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding SwitchViewModel}" >
                        <Run Text="Switch ViewModel" />
                    </Hyperlink>
      </TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
```

The parent ViewModel:

```
   public class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
      private ChildViewModel _vm1;
      private ChildViewModel _vm2;
      private ChildViewModel _currentChildVM;

      public ParentViewModel()
      {
         _vm1 = new ChildViewModel();
         _vm2 = new ChildViewModel();
         _currentChildVM = _vm1;
      }

      public ChildViewModel RadioButtonVM
      {
         get { return _currentChildVM; }
      }

      public ICommand SwitchViewModel
      {
         get
         {
            return new RelayCommand(p =>
            {
               if (_currentChildVM == _vm1)
                  _currentChildVM = _vm2;
               else
                  _currentChildVM = _vm1;

               // Update the view
               OnPropertyChanged("RadioButtonVM");
            });
         }
      }
```

The child view:

```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <RadioButton Name="IsProtectedGroupFalse" GroupName="IsProtectedGroup" Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding IsProtected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}">
         <Label Content="False" Target="{Binding ElementName=IsProtectedGroupFalse}" />
      </RadioButton>
      <RadioButton Name="IsProtectedGroupTrue" GroupName="IsProtectedGroup" Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding IsProtected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}">
         <Label Content="True" Target="{Binding ElementName=IsProtectedGroupTrue}" />
      </RadioButton>
   </StackPanel>
```

The child ViewModel:

```
   public class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
      bool _isProtected;

      public bool IsProtected
      {
         get
         {
            return _isProtected;
         }
         set
         {
            if (_isProtected == value)
               return;

            _isProtected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsProtected");
         }
      }
   }
```

The converter:

```
   class BooleanToRadioButtonConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         // Debug.WriteLine("    " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff") + "  BooleanToRadioButtonConverter::Convert");

         bool param = bool.Parse(parameter.ToString());
         if (value == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
         else
            return !((bool)value ^ param);
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         Debug.WriteLine("    " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff") + "  BooleanToRadioButtonConverter::ConvertBack, value=" + value.ToString() + ", parameter=" + parameter.ToString());

         bool param = bool.Parse(parameter.ToString());
         if (value == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
         else
            return !((bool)value ^ param);
      }
   }
```

**Update**

Following Rachel's advice I replaced the RadioButtons with a CheckBox where the problem described above does not occur. I still do not know why it works the way it does, though.

Comment: Does it work correctly without your Converter?

Comment: @Rachel: How can I bind the two RadioButtons to a single boolean value without that converter?

Comment: I usually have a `ReverseBooleanConverter` which simply returns the reverse of a boolean value, so one radio button would use the converter, and one wouldn't. I'm not that familiar with the `^` operator, but I was thinking they both evaluate to false, so would unset your radio button, which was why I was wondering if it worked correctly without the converter. Also, usually when working with RadioButtons I prefer to track the SelectedIndex in view model, not a true/false value. If I have a true/false value in the view model, I try and use a CheckBox in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue for the time being by adding an "active" property to the child ViewModel and manually setting that to true or false depending on whether the ViewModel is currently bound to the View or not. I do not consider that an ideal solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like pretty standard behaviour to me. The reason it happens is that you are changing the ViewModel that the radio buttons are bound to, and your new ViewModel doesn't have the same values as the previous.

If you need to seed your new VM instance with data, make the change to the new instances property before you bind to the new instance to the datacontext.

Comment: The RadioButtons are set to the value of the new ViewModel allright, there is no problem with that. What bugs me is that the old ViewModel's state gets reset right before that happens. I cannot have that since I want the user to be able to switch between ViewModels.

Comment: So you're saying that the values in VM1 get reset when you change to VM2?

Comment: yes, exactly: VM1 gets reset when I switch to VM2. But the reset only happens for the VM property the RadioButtons are bound to.

Comment: I have a suspicion it's to do with your `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;` in your value converter. Pop a breakpoint in there and see if it is being hit when you change VM's

Comment: The lines with UnsetValue are not being called. I just checked that in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Default value of a boolean is false. So, when you unbind the DataContext to that RadioButton it's IsChecked property returns to the default state of false.

Comment: Why are other controls in the user control not reset to the default state, e.g. TextBoxes?